# <br> causing with spaces

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

I am currently trying to have a `integrated register page` for two type of users using drop down list to show/hide certain labels and text-boxes for each type of user. (Using `visible="false"`)

But what I have noticed is that when certain labels/textboxes are hidden. The `<br>` tag at the end of it causes a white space in between two other labels/textboxes that's not hidden.

My question is - is there anyway to dynamically add `<br>` when I decided to show those hidden labels/textboxes? or is there a better way to integrate two register page into one?`

Comment: Are you actually doing ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Make two different `div` for both type of user.
In first div keep the `labels and textboxes` which u wanna show for first type of user and second div for 2nd type of user as

```
<div id="firsttype">Labels and textboxes</div>
<div id="secondtype">Labels and textboxes</div>
```

Comment: I have thought of something like this as well. But the problem here is there's some labels/textboxes that I want to use for both type of users. One of the obvious examples are username.

Comment: ahh. okay. I guess that's the way I should do it then. Separate them by divs.